# ionic scheduled notification fires immediately after code execution

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, notifications

I am trying to create scheduled notifications for my ionic project. I want the notification to happen 2 days before the event date.  When I test the notification on the device, the notification always fires immediately after the code is executed instead of at the later scheduled date.

I have the following code to handle the scheduled notifications:

```
// event date
let eventDate = new Date('2018-06-29T10:04:11.174Z');
// 2 days before event date
let notificationDate = new Date(eventDate.getTime() - 2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
// schedule notification
this.localNotifications.schedule({
  text: 'my notification text',
  trigger: {at: notificationDate},
  led: 'FF0000',
  sound: null
});
```

Comment: I have the same problem.... Did u solved it?

Comment: Hi Grzegorz G, yes I did. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was I was using a older version of the cordova local notification plugin and the trigger property is not available in that version...

The trigger property was introduced in the later recent version.  Before that it only accept a 'at' property.  After I updated my plugin, the problem was solved.